# Java's createNewFile() - will it also create directories?

Tags: java, file, io, directory

I've got a conditional to check if a certain file exists before proceeding (`./logs/error.log`). If it isn't found I want to create it. However, will

```
File tmp = new File("logs/error.log");
tmp.createNewFile();
```

also create `logs/` if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

No.
Use `tmp.getParentFile().mkdirs()` before you create the file.

Comment: Oops. I was using "tmp.mkdirs()". That's why my file was being created as a folder

Answer (score 22):

```
File theDir = new File(DirectoryPath);
if (!theDir.exists()) theDir.mkdirs();
```

Comment: I propose to use "mkdirs" instead of "mkdir" so your code can also create non-existing parent folders :)

Answer (score 14):

```
File directory = new File(tmp.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath());
directory.mkdirs();
```

If the directories already exist, nothing will happen, so you don't need any checks.

Answer (score 10):

Java 8 Style

```
Path path = Paths.get("logs/error.log");
Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());
```

To write on file

```
Files.write(path, "Log log".getBytes());
```

To read

```
System.out.println(Files.readAllLines(path));
```

Full example

```
public class CreateFolderAndWrite {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get("logs/error.log");
            Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());

            Files.write(path, "Log log".getBytes());

            System.out.println(Files.readAllLines(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`StringUtils.touch(/path/filename.ext)` will now (>=1.3) also create the directory and file if they don't exist.

Comment: Pardon the late comment but this should now be `FileUtils.touch(new File(file_path))`

Answer (score 0):

No, and if `logs` does not exist you'll receive `java.io.IOException: No such file or directory`

Fun fact for android devs: calls the likes of `Files.createDirectories()` and `Paths.get()` would work when supporting min api 26.