# How can I solve the error of the "no such a directory or file"?

Tags: java, android, audio, fingerprint, musicg

I have this simple code, but when I run, I get an error of not such a directory or file! how can I solved I tried many ways none of them works!! can anyone help?

public static void main (String [] args) {

```
    String songA = ("res/raw/canon_d_major.wav");
    String songB = ("res/raw/canon_d_major.wav");

    Wave waveA = new Wave(songA);
    Wave waveB = new Wave(songB);

    String recordedClip = ("res/raw/cock_a.1.wav");
    Wave waveRec = new Wave(recordedClip);

    FingerprintSimilarity similarity1, similarity2;

    similarity1= waveA.getFingerprintSimilarity(waveRec);

    System.out.println("clip is found at " + 
    similarity.getsetMostSimilarTimePosition() + "s in " + songA + 
    " with similarity " + similarity.getSimilarity());

    similarity2 = waveB.getFingerprintSimilarity(waveRec);

    System.out.println("clip is found at " + 
    similarity.getsetMostSimilarTimePosition() + "s in " + songB + 
    " with similarity " + similarity.getSimilarity());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`File fileName = new File('path/to/file');` does not create file on your hdd. Its only new File object in java that points to the dir you set in constructor. With that said if cock_a.wav doesnt exist while code is executing it wont be physically created.

Use this -> [Java's createNewFile() - will it also create directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666303/javas-createnewfile-will-it-also-create-directories)

Also it might be helpful if you post your directory structure here.

Comment: Show your directory structure. Keep in mind that above applies also to your other .wav files. Can you upload error stack trace?

Comment: Dear, thank you but I solved the problem, the path I provided was wrong, I just copy the path of each audio, now I am getting the results :)